# TouchPad not working Dell Latitude E5420

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lts

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Latitude E5420 (I have windows 7 ultimate also installed) The mouse touchpad does not work. I am **very new** to linux and Ubuntu. Can someone help with easy step-by-step guide to fix this please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This used to happen to me a fair bit. To fix it, open a terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T), then type:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

This should tell your synaptics driver to enable your touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Ubuntu help page, as directly applies to your question. Instructions are clear, and fairly verbose, should get you headed in the right direction:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Hope it helps, good luck.